# Adiabatic equation of state for a star

Tags: astrophysics, stars, adiabatic, convection, virial-theorem

I am a little confused. To describe stars the adiabatic equation is often used: P = k$\rho^{\gamma}$. For a monatomic gas, the following holds: $\gamma = \frac{5}{3}$.
However, since the sun is not fully convective, $\gamma = \frac{4}{3}$ is often used.

But doesn't that contradict itself? If I use the adiabatic equation P = k$\rho^{\gamma}$, I already assume that mainly convection takes place, or not? Can I use this equation for a star whose energy transport is mostly radiative and therefore not adiabatic?

Also, I read that the Virial Theorem is used for a star. $\Omega_{potE} + 3(\gamma-1)U_{thermE}= 0$.

Here, too, only $\gamma = \frac{5}{3}$ is used most of the time. And it is said that when $\gamma$ approaches $\frac{4}{3}$ the star becomes unstable because then $\Omega = -U$ and $E_{total}=\Omega + U \approx 0$ holds.
Wouldn't that mean that our sun is unstable? Since we said before that $\gamma = \frac{4}{3}$ is valid for the sun?

Comment: I think you shoud read Virial Theorem in Goldstein's book again

Comment: $\gamma$ of 4/3 would not be appropriate for the whole Sun, only the region where energy transport is totally dominated by radiation.

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/does-eddingtons-variable-polytropic-index-better-fit-data-from-the-standard-sol